# Wait random time of 5 to 30 seconds in batch file

Tags: batch-file, time

I am making a batch file to do something and wait a random 5 to 30 seconds and do next thing, I don’t know how to do this, is it `timeout %Random%`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
@echo off
set /a rand=%random% %%26+5
timeout /t %rand%
```

We just do random to higest 26, then add 5 to ensure we don't go below 5.